# Wordpress - decimal ,00 after price

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to remove the -,00 after a price in a form, but if its -,50 for example it should be displayed. (I am not using WooCommerce, which are the bulk of results I get when googling this issue)

If I try to delete this bit it immediatly changes it back to *example_price*,00 €

[image: When removing the -,00 it immediatly adds it back]

Comment: please share screenshot

Comment: @VasimShaikh Edited

Comment: is this plugin?

Comment: Yes, it is made in GravityForms

Comment: Try this once https://tompai.pro/wordpress/solved-woocommerce-thousands-separator-comma-coming-back/  remove , in woo-commerce setting

Comment: @HarshKhare I am not using WooCommerce, and it doesn't let me remove the comma in GravityForms

Answer (score 0):

Add the sample code below to your child theme's functions.php file or in a site specific plugin.

```
<?php
//* Do NOT include the opening php tag

//* Remove decimals from total calculation in Gravity Forms
function gf_update_currency( $currencies ) {
    $currencies['USD'] = array(
    'name' => __( 'U.S. Dollar', 'gravityforms' ),
    'symbol_left' => '$',
    'symbol_right' => '',
    'symbol_padding' => '',
    'thousand_separator' => ',',
    'decimal_separator' => '.',
    'decimals' => 0
);
return $currencies;
}
add_filter( 'gform_currencies', 'gf_update_currency' );
```

Comment: This unfortunately won't do, since there will also be options that have 19,50 as a price, for example. Therefore I need the decimals just not the 00 part. Thanks for helping me figuring out where to be, though.